# C# get element by name

Tags: c#, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbyname

So I've figured out how to get an element by id, but I don't know how I can get an element by name.

```cs
private void SendData()
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textfield1")
        .SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textfield2")
        .SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
}
```

The problem is in HTML `textfield1` is an id but `textfield2` is a name. So I want to figure out how to get `textfield2`:

```html
<html>
    <input type="text" id="textfield1" value="TEXT1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="textfield2" value="TEXT2"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</html>
```

Comment: What is webBrowser1, and Document? What library/framweork are you using?

Comment: @kai It is a simple `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` and its `HtmlDocument`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get an `HtmlElementCollection` - for example, using `GetElementsByTagName` method. Then, `HtmlElementCollection` has `GetElementsByName` method:

```
webBrowser1.Document
    .GetElementsByTagName("input")
    .GetElementsByName("textfield2")[0]
        .SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [HtmlElementCollection.GetElementsByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelementcollection.getelementsbyname(v=vs.110).aspx) to take the value of the elements

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("textfield2").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
```

### EDIT

```
foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("textfield2"))
{
    he.SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the code works as intended? .GetElementsByName SHOULD return an array so you would have to use [0] before the .SetAttribute or am I mistaken there?

Comment: For some reason, I do not have such method... I am using .NET 4.5.

Comment: `HtmlDocument` contains no such method, this doesn't compile.

Comment: webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("textfield2").SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("login_buton").InvokeMember("click"); i tryed this but cant get it to work do i gota add something inn my codes or?

Comment: hi, webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("textfield2").SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text); will get elements collections not a single element like in getelementbyid. please try webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("textfield2")[0]
        .SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text); If not working can you post what exactly the error code is. I'm wondering if the html is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the elements directly by name, but you could access it by finding the input tags first, and indexing into the result to find the tags by name.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")["textfield2"]
```

or

```
webBrowser1.Document
    .GetElementsByTagName("input")
    .GetElementsByName("textfield2")[0]
```